Let's Encypt SSL certificate not working on android device which is version 7 older
Some information has been announced regarding SSL no longer being supported on Android versions 7 and older: https://help.heroku.com/LBVEYASY/acm-certificate-compatibility-faq.
Is there any solution for SSL to work on Android versions 7 and older?"
